# locating map to center without refreshing

Tags: iphone, mapkit

I am using:

```
[mapView setRegion: animated:];
[mapView regionThatFits:];
```

methods in oder to bring map view to center after regular intervals of time but i don't want to refresh map or say locate updated locations.

How can i bring map to center (or current location) without refreshing?

Is there any method?

Please give some options clearly as I am new to objective C.

Answer (score 0):

Did you try:

```
setCenterCoordinate:animated
```